# How to change line width of map.scale from package maps?

Tags: r, maps

I'm using `map.scale()` from package `maps` to create a scale in a map. The following code creates an example of what I'm looking for:

```
library(maps)
png("example.png", width = 6000, height = 6000)
map(database = "world", regions = 'Brazil',fill = T)
map.scale(-43, -30, 
          ratio = F, 
          cex = 9, 
          lheight= 1, 
          pos =1,
          offset = 1)
dev.off()
```

As I'm creating a high resolution png image, the line width of the scale produced is not appropriate. You can check it by zooming in the lower right corner of the map.

Is there any parameter that I'm missing to increase the width of the scale?

Comment: Strange, `lwd` should work as they mention 'Further plotting parameters may be specified as for the command text().' on the help page to `map.scale`. Most likely, the developers of `maps` package forgot to include the parameter. (off-top: better to use `ggplot2` for mapping).

Comment: @Ilya Yes, it looks like the parameter was forgotten. By the way, what are the advantages of using `ggplot2` over base `plot` for mapping?

Comment: It's just that `ggplot2` is a proper ecosystem based on (arguably) intuitive grammar of graphics. You can control virtually  **everything** in `ggplot2`. 
Considering mapping, it's much more convenient to draw a map layer by layer having each change stored in an object. The ability to store a plot as an object help a lot when you want to create a set of similar maps (i.e. time series). Also, trivial operations like merge and reproject are easier with `ggplot2`.

Comment: There are multiple add-ons for `ggplot2`. For example, package `viridis` (`devtools::install_github("sjmgarnier/viridis")`) which is the best ever color palette [more info](https://rud.is/b/2015/07/20/using-the-new-viridis-colormap-in-r-thanks-to-simon-garnier/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't modify the line width (it's the `lwd` argument you should be looking for not line height here) is that it isn't applied in the `map.scale()` function and passed on to the `lines()` call for that part of the scale.  We can, however, programmatically add this functionality to the function by doing something like this:

```
library(maps)


t <- capture.output(map.scale)
##  Strip trailing text:
t <- t[-length(t)]

##  Find lines() call and add in a line width argument:
t <- gsub("(lines\\(linexy)", "\\1, lwd=lwd", t)
t <- gsub("(\\.\\.\\.)", "\\1, lwd=10", t)
t <- paste(t, collapse="\n")
eval( parse(text=paste0( "map.scale.new <- ", t )) )

##  Use our new map.scale.new() function with lwd= parameter:
png("example.png", width = 6000, height = 6000)
map(database = "world", regions = 'Brazil',fill = T)
map.scale.new(
  -43, -30, 
  ratio = F, 
  cex = 9, 
  lwd= 10, 
  pos =1,
  offset = 1
)
dev.off()
```

You can modify the `lwd=` to now suit your fancy.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I had the option to implement a parameter like this! I'll test it.